# LINQ navigation property multiple sources

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a database which stores different locations. Based on the type of the location, the unique details are stored in a different table than the common properties (i.e. Name, Coordinates, Description are stored in the `Locations` table, while Population is stored in the `CityDetails` table).
The tables are connected via FK in the "specific details" table.
Since there are more than one "specific details" table I'm scratching my head how to query those multiple tables.
My Location object looks like this:

```
[Table("Locations")]
public class LocationData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // multiple different properties here.

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public DetailsData { get; set; }
}
```

based on the `Type` property I can see which details table I have to query. A details table looks at least like this:

```
public abstract class DetailsData 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Location")]
    public Guid { get; set; }

    public LocationData Location { get; set; }
}
```

Every table that represents a location type then inherits from the `DetailsData` class and is configured to use the "Table-per-concrete-class" inheritance hierarchy.
Here is an example of what a "specific details" table might look like:

```
[Table("CityDetails")]
public class CityDetailsData : DetailsData
{
    public string Planet { get; set; }

    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

How can I populate the `DetailsData` property in the `Location` class. Here is my current LINQ query:

```
from l in Locations
select new
{
    Id = l.Id,
    Name = l.Name,
    Description = l.Description,
    Coordinates = l.Coordinates,
    Type = l.Type,
    DetailsData = CityDetails // Here lies the problem. How can I populate this property properly?
}
```

Comment: I assume all your "specific details" tables have different sets of columns?

Comment: Yes they do. I updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm working on the assumption that your details tables all have different sets of columns, that you want to be able to use `IEnumerable<LocationData>` instances, and that you want to be able to directly access the properties of the instances of whatever details table object you return.

That's a toughie. There are basically three ways you can write code for an object of unknown type:

1. Give it a type of `Object`.
2. Make all "details" tables inherit from a common interface, and make `CityDetails` an object that implements that interface.
3. Use a generic type, which means you do ultimately specify the type, but you can push that decision up the chain to a declarer of your implemented type.

Using `System.Object` means that you either need to cast all your `DetailsData` objects to the required type (or use Reflection to access their properties), whereas using an interface means you can access some properties directly, but probably not everything you want.

I think a generic type might be your best, hybrid, solution.

I would do something like this:

1. Accept that there isn't a perfect solution.
2. Instead of creating an anonymous type, as you are doing in your example code, define a class like this (akin to a ViewModel, if you're using ASP.NET MVC):

   ```
   public class LocationViewModel<TDetailsData>
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }

       // multiple different properties here.

       public string Type { get; set; }

       public TDetailsData DetailsData { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Define a helper method that takes a type parameter and returns a value of type `TDetailsData`.  Use that to populate your `DetailsData` property on `LocationViewModel`.

   ```
    TDetailsData GetLocationDetails<TDetailsData>(string type, Guid ID)
    {
        // get the appropriate data based on the type.
    }
   ```
4. If you need to keep an `IEnumerable` of these objects, define an interface `ILocationDataViewModel` and another of `ILocationDataViewModel<TDetailsData>`, make `LocationViewModel` implement both of them, and use `IEnumerable<ILocationDataViewModel>` or `IEnumerable<ILocationDataViewModel<CityDetailsData>>`, etc.,  as called for by the situation.

Comment: See my updated question. Each details table has a different set of properties/columns but all inherit from the same abstract class `DetailsData`. This abstract class is also the type of the class used as the property type in the main `LocationData` class. I should add, that this data is going to be converted into a slightly different type of data for use in other parts of the program. Basically I need an IEnumerable<LocationData> with LocationData.Details populated from one of the different details tables.

Comment: If you don't care about intellisense or easy access to property values when using specific instances of `LocationData`, can't you just write a helper method that uses the parameter `type` to check the appropriate detail table and returns a `DetailsData`?

Comment: No I don't really car about intellisense at that point. My workflow is like this: 1. Query the locations table. 2. Query the appropriate details table and store it inside the `Details` property. 3. Return it to the repository. 4. pass it to the converter 5. Return the converted data to the user.    I'll try your idea. It is so simply I totally forgot about it...

Comment: @Ruhrpottpatriot LOL!  I gave you an over-complicated answer because I thought, "the problem can't be that simple!  He must be asking for something very subtle!"

Comment: It probably is this simple. The problem was: I create a Request for a service manager to handle (has something to do how the repository works, since it can use multiple sources (i.e. Database or webApi) of data based on request and service manager). A request against a database is a `Func<TIn, TOut>` expression. I was not sure if I could do something simple like a method call. Or better: I was sure it has to be done in LINQ. Well I missed the wood for the trees... *lol*

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would like to dynamically determine the type and deal with it on the fly. In that case, you can go with [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). I have not tested this code, but you can think in that line

```
        public DetailsData GetDetailsData(Type t) 
        {
            dynamic typVal = new ExpandoObject();

            if(t == typeof(CityDetails))
            {
                typVal = new CityDetails();
            }
            // add other types

            return (DetailsData)PopulateDetailsData(typVal);
        }

        public DetailsData PopulateDetailsData(CityDetails cd)
        {
            cd.Planet = new CityDetails().Planet;
            return cd;
        }

        // Add other type related methods with same 
        // signature with input parameter differentiated by types
        // for example
        public DetailsData PopulateDetailsData(TownDetails td)
        {
            td.Income = new TownDetails().Income;
            return td;
        }
```

in query, you can have something like below

```
from l in Locations
select new
{
    Id = l.Id,
    Name = l.Name,
    Description = l.Description,
    Coordinates = l.Coordinates,
    Type = l.Type,
    DetailsData = GetDetailsData(l.Type)
}
```